# How to update a printed line, along with an input

Tags: python, printing, stdout

I'm currently working on a puzzle program, and I need to be able to update a line, based on what the player wants to do. This is the basic idea:

```
>>> A B C D E
>>> Would you like to nudge left or right [L/R] ?
```

Asking to nudge should change the top line, so it shows this:

```
>>> E A B C D
>>> Would you like to nudge left or right [L/R] ?
```

(I'd also need it to remove the 'L' for nudge left) I know how to update a line by using `sys.stdout`, but I don't know how to do this whilst also factoring in an input. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is print on a previous line cannot be changed

Comment: @azro You can, using ```sys.stdout```, I just need to do this with an input...

Comment: Might want to take a look at [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html)

Comment: @Jon Clements I'm having a fair bit of trouble with curses, apparently there's no distribution for it?